# div not containing content floats have been cleared

Tags: css, html, css-float, z-index

I have a bunch of divs I'm trying to organize here.  The ones I'm having trouble with have been given a red border and a blue border, they are suppose to appear one after the other.  They do actually do this, red coming first and blue second, but there are several divs that are in the red layer, and instead of containing them it just sits on top of them.

There are floated layers, but I thought I had cleared this with a div called clear-fix.  The main containing div, the one with the inset box shadow had this  same problem and I had fixed it with that div, it now contains all the layers in it properly, so I'm not sure why it's not also doing this to the red layer.  Help please!

http://jsfiddle.net/2TAaC/6/

Comment: can you show screen shot what exactly you want to achieve that will better because in your code so many divs are present and it is complicated without knowing what output we want.

Comment: yes http://klossal.com/portfolio/final.jpg the stack of images in contained in the div with the red border, but in that fiddle the div sits on top of the contents in stead of surrounding it.  I'd like it to surround what ever is inside of it (in this case the image stack) and push the div with the blue layer down.  It seems like it would all work fine but the red layer just isn't wrapping around the contents.

Comment: check the answer and let me now if any issues are still present.

Comment: so I'd like to do it with out setting a height.  If that's possible.

Comment: Dear Check the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you have to do is...

```
<div id="level4" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 4; position: relative;">
```

You can find this div inside your graphics DIV.

[image]

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/2TAaC/10/

Comment: I was hoping to have it regulate it's own height and wrap accordingly, I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't do that on it's own.  I've definitely had divs with out heights that are able to do this.

Comment: your other idv's have height such as spacecontainer and all they are conflicting, let me check once again..

Comment: well for example the div id="text" which is the blue div, the div is just the height of the invisible image contained inside of it.  There is not set height.

Comment: yes!  that's awesome, can you tell me what you changed, I can't find it.

Comment: there is a DIV in your graphics,<div id= "level 4"> just do `position :relative` instead of absolute this will work fine.

Comment: check the fiddle i removed the height and its working. no issues.

Answer (score 2):

See the updated fiddle:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2TAaC/12/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2TAaC/12/embedded/result/

Note: Your image is not present in blue border div thats why it is not taking the 150px height so thats why i put the height 150px; you just placed your imahe in blue border div and remove the height. it will work.

Comment: I was hoping to have it regulate it's own height and wrap accordingly, I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't do that on it's own. I've definitely had divs with out heights that are able to do this.

Comment: that's great, can you tell me what you changed, haha I can't see it.

Comment: Thank god it was totally confusing issue. I just set the position:inherit on level-4 element and set the height 150px temporary on blue border div. If still any issues you can tel me. And thanks for selecting my answer.

Comment: oh, wait, but the red div still has the height in it, it can't wrap around contents?  Giving the blue layer a height doesn't actually change anything because that div was already taking the height of the contents in it, so the image of 150 pixels high is what makes the blue layer have height, if I take away the height property of that div and change it to 200 pixels the blue layer becomes higher...make sense?  It can be done with out a height property being set to the div.